# Filter/Group by Data in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

we have data returned from rest service in below JSON format and I want to group data by `ActivityStartDate` [and then show in format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQBT9.png). I can iterate through and create group by `ActivityStartDate` but this seems not efficient method in case we have more items returned.

Is there any better way to achieve it?

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "Food Promotion - 1",
      "ActivityStartDate": "2015-12-12T08:00:00Z",
      "ActivityEndDate": "2016-01-12T08:00:00Z",
      "ActivityDescription": "Two for one if dream and do not dream of fack promotions",
      "ShowInHistory": true,
      "ShowUpdated": true,
      "Modified": "2015-12-14T21:28:37Z",
      "Created": "2015-12-14T21:28:37Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the REST API you're using allow you to query by group? If not, you may just have to write a function to iterate over the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason to group in front end

Assuming you can get a collection from the back end by `GET /activities`. If the returned *JSON array* is either **small** or **pre-sorted** it may be just more flexible to group late (in front end). This labor division between front and back end follows [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end):

> terms front end and back end refer to the **separation of concerns** between the **presentation layer** (front end), and the **data access layer** (back end)

Limitations: Data should be *small* because then it can be completely fetched and independently sorted in the front end. Contrary big data can lead to performance issues when loading/grouping. Thus it should be *pre-sorted* on the server, which can be achieved if your REST API (back end) supports *sorting/paging* for collection resources.

#### How to group in Angular

See [typescript1.7 - How to group data in Angular 2? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248580/how-to-group-data-in-angular-2) with advice on Angular's [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) demonstrated on Plunkr in answer.

Similar for older AngularJS there is a [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) component achieving the same goal:
transformation/grouping/filtering of data.