# Angular 2 - ngFor index after a pipe

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 when using ngFor how would I get the original index for an object within an array after it has been passed through a pipe?

For example if I have an array of objects as follows:

```
list =  [{type:"A",id:111},{type:"A",id:222},{type:"B",id:333},{type:"A",id:444},{type:"B",id:555}];
```

And using the following pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'appFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class AppFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
// Single Argument Filter
  transform(values: any[], arg1: any, arg2: any): any {
    return values.filter(value => value[arg1] === arg2);
  }
}
```

I create an ngFor as follows:

```
<div *ngFor= "let item of list|AppFilter:'type':'B'|let index=index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
 {{index}} - {{item.id}}
 <input [(ngModel)]="list[index]" placeholder="item">
</div>
```

The issue here is the index returned by the ngFor is based on new array returned by AppFilter that is index 0 and 1. This will cause the input field to reference the wrong index ie it will show the type A objects as it corresponds to index 0,1 in the original list. To get Type B I really need the index 2,4.

Appreciate a work around to this. Also my trackByIndex in the component currently looks like:

```
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

Comment: I think it would be best to filter before you assign to `list`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use `reduce` method to keep original index:

```typescript
@Pipe({
  name: 'appFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class AppFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any[], arg1: any, arg2: any): any {
    return values.reduce((acc, value, index) => 
       value[arg1] === arg2 ? [...acc, { index, value }] : acc, []);
  }
}
```

and then in html

```typescript
{{item.index}} - {{item.value.id}}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lB5iInd2P23EeWsjsUSO)**

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you want index of original list, in that case you can use that filtered object to find out origin index from original list.

```
<div *ngFor= "let item of list|appFilter:'type':'B'|let index=index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
 {{getIndex(iteml)}} - {{item.id}}
  <input [(ngModel)]="list[getIndex(item)].id" placeholder="item">
</div>
```

and then define geIndex method in you component which can return Index from original list which is not been filtered.

```
getIndex(item: Item) {
    return this.list.indexOf(this.list.filter((i, index) => item.id == i.id)[0])
}
```

Comment: This is one of my approach at the beginning but I think the reason to keep the original index is to not for calculating the index again to save some memory. If we have a huge list, finding index again will be too expensive.

Comment: @trungk18 another way would be that you map map once your list with index so you have index of each item in list and you don't need to any more loop at all.

Comment: Yeah, probably we do the map at the beginning and save the index inside the object.

Comment: This approach seems like it does multiple item seeks, which will not scale.