# Applying pipe to array but keeping original index

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-pipe

I have the following HTML:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-supplier[ngForOf]="allSuppliers | search: searchTerm"  let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
...
</ng-template>
```

And I'd like to know whether is possible to have the index position within the array of the elements resulted by applying the pipe search. If I have the elements 1, 2, 3 and by applying the pipe I got elements 1 and 3, id like to have the index to be 1 = 0 and 3 = 2 if that makes sense.
I can extend the collection with an extra field "`originalPosition`" or something along those lines however I don't know if Angular offers a solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Actually a solution for this is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340661/angular-2-ngfor-index-after-a-pipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - ngFor index after a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340661/angular-2-ngfor-index-after-a-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

you can split pipe usages

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of y | fn:'val'; let i = index"> ->
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let tx of y; let i = index">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let x of [tx] | fn:'val'>
```

or invoke the filter manually with an ngIf