# How to push filter index instead of array index in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I am having two arrays of object A and B between which I push objects. When I did not use filter everything works, that is, I can push object from B to A and the object is moved from B to A.

But I am have a problem with the filter, that is, when I filter out e.g "Benz" which on a good day the last object in array B, and click add button, object "BMW" is the one been added to array A instead of "Benz". Meaning that index of array B is added instead of "filter index".

How do make my button to push filter index instead of index of array B? See my code sample below.

**ts**

```
A = [{"name": "Ford"}]
B = [{"name": "BMW"}, {"name": "Toyota"}, {"name": "Jeep"}, {"name": "Benz"}]

addItem(i) {
  this.A.push(this.B[i]);
  this.B.splice(i, 1);
}
```

**html**

```
<input class="form-control col-md-8" type="search" [(ngModel)]="filterFunction" placeholder="filter here">

<tr *ngFor="let fromB of B | filterBy: filterFunction; let i=index;">
    <td><button type="button" (click)="addItem(i)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
    </td>
 .........
</tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - ngFor index after a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340661/angular-2-ngfor-index-after-a-pipe)

Comment: No, but thanks anyway...