# Group Javascript Array Using Lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, ionic3

*Transaction.ts*

```
export class Transaction {
    id: string;
    category: Category = new Category();
    totalPrice: number;
}
```

*Category .ts*

```
export class Category {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I have an array of `Transaction` as shown below.

```
id:"1"
category: {id: "1", name: "Plumber"}
totalPrice: 500

id:"2"
category: {id: "1", name: "Plumber"}
totalPrice: 500

id:"3"
category: {id: "2", name: "Electrician"}
totalPrice: 1000
```

Now I need to group that data as shown below.

[image]

I have tried to group it using [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy). But unable to format the way which I need (as shown above). Can I have any support here?

This is what I tried. It just returned individual objects. After that?

```
let myArray = groupBy(this.data.transactions, (n) => {
      return n.category.name;
    });
```

Like this (data is different here.Just dummy data)

[image]

**Update:**

```
 let a = groupBy(this.data.transactions, (n) => {
      return n.category.name;
    }).map((objs, key) => ({
      'name': key,
      'totalPrice': sumBy(objs, 'totalPrice')
    })).value();
```

Above gives this error:

> core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   Object(...)(...).map is not a function TypeError: Object(...)(...).map
>   is not a function

**Update 2:**

```
  const resultArray = [...reduce(this.data.transactions,(r, { totalPrice, category: { name } }) => {
      const item = r.get(name) || {
        name,
        totalPrice: 0
      };

      item.totalPrice += totalPrice;

      return r.set(name, item);
    }, new Map()).values()];
```

**ERROR:**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   Object(...)(...).values(...).slice is not a function TypeError:
>   Object(...)(...).values(...).slice is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group data in Angular 2 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248580/how-to-group-data-in-angular-2)

Comment: Hope I don't need to write `pipe` here. This is just a matter of choosing correct `Lodash` methods. Please remove the duplicate tag. @RameshRajendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **`groupBy`** and **`sumBy`**,

```
var grouped =  _(jsonarray)
    .groupBy('category.name')
    .map((objs, key) => ({
        'name': key,
        'totalPrice': _.sumBy(objs, 'totalPrice') }))
    .value();
```

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonarray = [{id:"1",
category: {id: "1", name: "Plumber"},
totalPrice: 500
},
{
id:"2",
category: {id: "1", name: "Plumber"},
totalPrice: 500
},
{
id:"3",
category: {id: "2", name: "Electrician"},
totalPrice: 1000
}];



var grouped =  _(jsonarray)
    .groupBy('category.name')
    .map((objs, key) => ({
        'name': key,
        'totalPrice': _.sumBy(objs, 'totalPrice') }))
    .value();

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Oh.. It's like a tsunami of Downvotes? I'm still trying to see your solution. But it is grayed :D

Comment: did you run the demo and see

Comment: Is this lodash method `groupBy` and `map`?

Comment: Here it gives this error: `core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...)(...).map is not a function
TypeError: Object(...)(...).map is not a function`

Comment: Can you see the **Update** section on my post?

Comment: Can you please **Delete** your answer? It doesn't work due to I'm using lodash modules. I'm going to delete this question. Thanks for your support.

Comment: you can import loadash and use it

Comment: why not? its working on mine! can you create a demo?

Comment: Yes. I didn't use it properly with lodash modules.This answer inspired me and your one also should work. Thanks a lot :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611526/groupby-with-lodash-module