# groupBy with Lodash module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash, ionic3

I have grouped using the lodash module as below:

```
export class DtoTransactionCategory {
    categoryName: String;
    totalPrice: number;
}
```

*groupBy*

```
import { groupBy} from 'lodash';

  let result = groupBy(transactionCategoryList, (c: DtoTransactionCategory) => {
      return c.categoryName
    });
```

*Result:*

[image]

So now I need to get the above array like this (i.e. `totalPrice` is the `sum` of the `group`):

```
let myNewArry = [{categoryName:"cat1",totalPrice: 9400},
                    {categoryName:"cat2",totalPrice: 600}]
```

Can you tell me how to achieve last step? I'm using `Lodash modules` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = {
cat1: [{totalPrice: 2}, {totalPrice: 3}],
cat2: [{totalPrice: 2}, {totalPrice: 5}]
}
const totals = _.map(result, (val, key) => ({categoryName: key, totalPrice: _.sumBy(val, 'totalPrice')}))

console.log(totals)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally got a solution.Thank you :)