# Custom Pipe Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Tags: angular, undefined, typeerror, angular-pipe

I am fetching the courses from the Firebase database as so:

```
              this.fetchItems()
              .subscribe((res) => {
                   this.coursesFiltered = res.filter((filtered: any) => {
                    return filtered.courseStatus === 2 || filtered.courseStatus === 3
                   });


               });
```

The function fetchItems()

```
  fetchItems() {
    return this.afDB.list('courses', (ref) => ref.orderByChild('courseSemCode'))
       .snapshotChanges()
       .map((arr) => {
          return arr.map((snap: any) => {
            return snap.status = snap.payload.val();
          });
        });
      }
```

Then I want to group them by courseSemCode so that it displays properly in the cards

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of coursesFiltered | groupBy:'courseSemCode'">
    <ion-card-header>
      <h6>{{item.courseSemester + " " + item.courseYear}}</h6>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>

        <ion-list>
            <button ion-button class="text" class="btnCourse">
              {{item.courseName}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

The groupBy pipe is a custom pipe that I got from this thread:
[How to group data in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248580/how-to-group-data-in-angular-2)

Which is this:

```
    @Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any> 
{
  if(!value || !value.length) { 
    return value; 
  }else{
    const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
      if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
        prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
      } else {
        prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
      }
      return prev;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
  }
  }  
}
```

But unfortunately in the end I'm faced with the problem
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

I believe this has to do with the .subscribe which I've written in the constuctor, which only means that the coursesFiltered still has no data.

How can I make sure it does and solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the `async` pipe to display data, or are you using a variable ?

Comment: @trichetriche I'm only using groupBy as pipe

Comment: okay, then see my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pipe, you can simply test for it :

```
transform(value: any, args?: any) {
  if(!value || !value.length) { return value; }
  return value.reduce(...);
}
```

**EDIT** In your loop you do this

```
*ngFor="let item of coursesFiltered | groupBy:'courseSemCode'"
```

But your structure for the grouped array is this

```
[{key: 'your key', value: [...]}]
```

This means that you have to make two loops :

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let group of coursesFiltered | groupBy:'courseSemCode'">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of group.value">
    <ion-card-header>
      <h6>{{item.courseSemester + " " + item.courseYear}}</h6>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>

        <ion-list>
            <button ion-button class="text" class="btnCourse">
              {{item.courseName}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ng-container>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: It also did help remove the error, but I only see "undefined" now where the proper values should be.

Comment: A lot of undefined or only just one ?

Comment: All of the fields where "item." they all show undefined

Comment: Then your pipe isn't working. Could you share your pipe code ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is failing when it is evaluating before coursesFiltered is set.  Maybe initialise coursesFiltered to an empty array.

```
this.coursesFiltered: any[] = [];
```

Comment: It did help me display the app without errors but everything is showing "undefined".