# Using *ngFor with async pipe with conditional display in html in angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

## .html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of listContact | async; let index = index;">
      <h6 class="title" *ngIf="contact && contact['type']">
        {{contact['type']}}
        </h6>
   <div> {{contact['id']}}</div>
 </ng-container>
```

## listContact an observable contains:-

```
[
  {
    "id": "u-8cf4161b-240f-5d7a-b5df-0522739c62d9",
    "type": "Peoples"
  },
  {
    "id": "u-0580ff64-c959-5690-bc54-16c43b28065d",
    "type": "Peoples"
  },
  {
    "id": "u-44e5a40a-a367-55e0-baf1-1eacccafe5f2",
    "type": "Teams"
  }
]
```

## The expected(desired) html output:-

```
Peoples

u-8cf4161b-240f-5d7a-b5df-0522739c62d9
u-0580ff64-c959-5690-bc54-16c43b28065d

Teams
u-44e5a40a-a367-55e0-baf1-1eacccafe5f2
```

How to add a check that if previous `{{contact['type']}}` in for loop is same as current `{{contact['type']}}` in for loop , then not add `{{contact['type']}}` in view. title is dependent on `{{contact['type']}}` and too should not repeat until previous `{{contact['type']}}` is different from current one.

How to handle it in html for this issue?

Comment: parse the listContact json array and do the manipulations in TypeScript and bind it.

Comment: can you explain it more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle it would be grouping your items into categories like `Peoples`, `Teams`, etc.

But if you want to check your condition in template then you can store the result of `listContact | async` extract into a variable and then use `index` on it:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of listContact | async as contacts; let index = index;">
  <h6 class="title" *ngIf="contact.type && (!contacts[index - 1] || contacts[index - 1].type !== contacts[index].type)">
     {{contact.type}}
  </h6>
  <div> {{contact.id}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/1LiwyPc8jgp06jLlrAXf)**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37250267/4964569) pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: "groupBy" })
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any> {
    const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur) => {
      if (!prev[cur[field]]) {
        prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
      } else {
        prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
      }
      return prev;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({
      key,
      value: groupedObj[key]
    }));
  }
}
```

And use in html as

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of listContact | groupBy:'type'; let index = index;">
      <h6 class="title">
        {{contact.key}}
        </h6>
   <div *ngFor="let value of contact.value">{{value.id}}</div>
 </ng-container>
```

Stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-groupby-pipe?